# IBKR trading questions

Tags: trading, day-trading

IBKR account FAQ says as follows. Would you explain what it means by "4 day trades in a rolling 5 day span"?

> "If you open an account with less than USD 25,000, you will be limited
>   to 4 day trades in a rolling 5 day span."
>   (https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=1560)

Comment: You've asked two completely different questions. I suggest you add the removed second one as a new question.

Answer (score 2):

This is part of the Pattern Day Trader rule.  However, you are limited to 3  trades (options and equities, not futures) in a rolling 5 day span not 4 trades. If you make 4 trades then you are labeled a pattern Day Trader and must maintain $25k of equity in your account at all times.

3 trades per week would be 3 trades this week and 3 trades next week, etc.

A rolling 5 day span is 5 consecutive trading days.  For example, M-T-W-T-F or T-W-T-F-M, etc.  As each day drops off of the current 5 day period, so too  do those trades made on that departed day, as applied to the total number of trades made.

Comment: Would you explain what is possible and what is not possible under this rule?

Comment: You must maintain $25k minimum equity on any day trades are made, prior to trading. If account falls below $25k,  will not be allowed to day trade until account restored to $25k minimum.  Benefit of  PDT is being able to intraday trade 4X maintenance margin excess from  close of business of the previous day but you must return to 2:1 overnight (50% margin). Brokers have the right to require higher margin levels as well as restrict margin on leveraged ETFs.

Comment: If the day-trading buying power limit is exceeded you'll be issued a day-trading margin call with at most, 5 business days to deposit funds to meet the call. Until call is met, day-trading restricted to 2X maintenance margin excess. If not met by the 5th business day,  account will be  restricted to trading only on a cash available basis for 90 days or until the call is met.